# What's the correct way to implement convolutional blocks of specified depth?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement bayesian optimization with Convolutional Neural Netowrk in PyTorch, specifically, I'm trying to translate network structure from Matlab BayesOptExperiment to PyTorch. I want my network to have the following structure:

Input data -> **convblock** -> maxpool -> **convblock** -> maxpool -> **convblock** -> avgpool -> flatten -> linear -> softmax

where **convblock** consists of:

[conv2Dlayer -> batch normalization layer -> ReLU],

repeated a few times. Current version works as expected only when `section_depth = 1` achieving accuracy of around 65-70%, although if I raise the depth of convblock accuracy plummets to around 10%. I'm definitely missing something, but I'm not sure what is that. The structure of my network:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

#...

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, section_depth):
        super().__init__()
        #! define network architecture
        self.section_depth = section_depth
        self.num_filters = round(16/np.sqrt(self.section_depth))
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=8)
        self.block1 = nn.ModuleList()
        self.block2 = nn.ModuleList()
        self.block3 = nn.ModuleList()
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.num_filters)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(2*self.num_filters)
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(4*self.num_filters)
        for i in range(self.section_depth):
            channels1 = 3 if i==0 else self.num_filters
            channels2 = self.num_filters if i == 0 else 2*self.num_filters
            channels3 = 2*self.num_filters if i == 0 else 4*self.num_filters
            self.block1.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels1, out_channels=self.num_filters, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
            self.block2.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels2, out_channels=2*self.num_filters, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
            self.block3.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels3, out_channels=4*self.num_filters, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*self.num_filters, 10)  # ? number of outputs
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        for i in self.block1:
            x = F.relu(self.batchnorm1(i(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        for i in self.block2:
            x = F.relu(self.batchnorm2(i(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        for i in self.block3:
            x = F.relu(self.batchnorm3(i(x)))
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `nn`, `F` and `torch` in the code please ?  please also confirm that `np` is `import numpy as np`...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about imports. `nn`, `F` and `torch` are torch imports, `np` is numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Turns out that batch normalization layer has learnable parameters, so instead of using the same layer for the whole convblock I had to make a separate batchnorm layer for every convolutional layer.